# Is it possible to set cache-from for bootBuildImage gradle task

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, spring-boot-docker-plugin

So, I am creating a Spring Boot Application Docker Image.
As I see, there is a plugin available for it which can be just invoked as a gradle task as

```
./gradlew bootBuildImage
```

If I am using this plugin, how do I mention the `--cache-from` option as if I am using the

`docker build  --cache-from old-image .`

Answer (score 0):

Appears this is not possible yet because there's an open ticket to add this functionality: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28386